# Extract a file name out of a path found in an ini file

Tags: string, batch-file

I need to extract information from a path found on a line in a batch file. Specifically the line says:

```
GLOBP4P=C:\folderx\foldery\folderz\datag.p4p
```

What I need to extract is the part above identified as "data". The `g.p4p` is always present, the `GLOBP4P` is always present, but the things in between can be varying from file to file. I essentially want to strip the `g.p4p` and then write whatever is left to the first `"\"` to a variable. in this case the variable would store `"data"`. The problem I have is that `"data"` can be any number of characters, also there can be any number of path folders, etc.

I attempted to do a`For /f with "\"` as a delim to try and break the string apart, but since i don't know how many folders there will be I don't know how to identify taking the last one (i.e. the filename) exclusively.

Thanks

Comment: findstr will perform regex pattern matching http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work too:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i "GLOBP4P=" "file.ini"') do set "var=%%~na"
set "var=%var:~0,-1%"
echo "%var%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set GLOBP4P=C:\folderx\foldery\folderz\datag.p4p

for %%a in ("%GLOBP4P%") do set var=%%~Na
set var=%var:~0,-1%
echo %var%
```

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

In a FOR command, `%%~N` return just the file name of the FOR parameter, in this case is `datag` string. Enter `FOR /?` for further details.

When a variable is expanded via `%var%`, the `%var:~START,LEN%` notation indicate to extract a substring starting at `START` character (beginning at zero) and with `LEN` characters. If `LEN` have minus sign, indicate the last character backwards from string end. In this case, `%var:~0,-1%` indicate to extract all but last characters from `var`, that is, eliminate the last character from `datag` string. Enter `SET /?` for further details.

Comment: Can you provide some expository for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will get the **LAST** occurence finded in your `ini` file :

```
@echo off

::The name of the bat file to test

Set $bat="The_ini_file_to_test.ini"

::Finding the string "GLOBP4P" and setting the value in it

for /f %%a in ('findstr /i "GLOBP4P" "%$bat%"') do set %%a

::Getting the first and the Last element of the path

set first=%GLOBP4P:\=&set last=%

::Outputting some results

echo File  : [%last%]
echo Data  : [%last:~0,-5%]
echo drive : [%first%]
```